# Use ffmpeg to achieve uniform output volume levels across different video recordings

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I record math lectures for my students using quicktime (audio and video). Quicktime does not offer much control over the input audio gain. I would like to make sure that all my recordings have the same output volume level. Is there a simple way to achieve this using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will require audio re-encoding: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioVolume

Also check: https://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg

Lastly normalization does not always help because you may have a relatively quiet audio track with peaks which will make normalization impossible. In this case you'll need to use dynamic range compression, e.g.

https://medium.com/@jud.dagnall/dynamic-range-compression-for-audio-with-ffmpeg-and-compand-621fe2b1a892

Comment: Many thanks! I'll have a look.